# Azure Maps clear map without affecting style

Tags: azure-maps

I have multiple rendering options exposed through a UI in my Azure maps application. When a user changes one of these options, then the whole map is re-rendered. This functionality uses `map.clear()` internally. However, after calling this method, the style of the map dissapears, which results in a *white background*. I did not find this effect in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.map?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest#azure-maps-control-atlas-map-clear).

I looked at the `map.getStyle()` properties after `map.clear()` and it seems that the style is still the same (starting with `style: 'road'` will still be `style: 'road'` after the `clear`), but it isn't visible until the user selects a new style from the controls. Changing the map style options after the `clear` to the map style options before the `clear` (`map.setStyle(oldStyleOptions, false)`) generates errors so that's also not possible. Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map.clear()` removes everything and in most cases, not what you will want.

If you simply want to remove all data on the map, but keep the rendering layers there, ready for new data later, use the data sources `clear` function. For example:

```
var source = new atlas.source.DataSource();
map.sources.add(source);

//Connect source to rendering layers...
//Add some data at some point....

//Later, decide to remove data from the map.
source.clear();
```

A key concept of Azure Maps is that is separates data from rendering layers. It's a bit different from older map SDKs, but it provides a lot more potential for performance and styling.

**Update** - 10/10/2023

Here is a function that will remove only content added by users of the map SDK, and not the basemap layers/sources.

```js
function removeUserContent(map) {
    //Remove popups.
    map.popups.clear();
    
    //Remove markers.
    map.markers.remove();
    
    //Get user layers. (workaround using undocumented method to get the layers created by the user). The response contains information about layers and what layer they are added before.
    var userLayerInfo = map.layers._getUserLayers();
    
    //Get the sources used by user layers that don't belong to the basemap.
    //Get user layer objects.
    var userSources = [];   
    var userLayers = [];
    
    userLayerInfo.forEach(l => {
        var sourceId = l.layer.options.source.id;
        if(sourceId !== 'bing-mvt' && userSources.indexOf(sourceId) === -1) {
            userSources.push(sourceId);
        }
        userLayers.push(l.layer);
    });
        
    //Remove user layers.
    map.layers.remove(userLayers);
    
    //Remove user sources.
    map.sources.remove(userSources);
    
    //Optional. Remove all user added images.
    map.imageSprite.clear();
}
```

Simply pass your map object into this function and it will do the rest.

Comment: So it is not possible to remove everything at once from the map (all user created things such as layers/popups/...) in one command, without affecting the rendering of the map itself?

Comment: I've also seen that changing the map style with the user controls (e.g. road to grayscale) seems to change the layer ordering. My map has a symbol layer that is drawn under a text layer. The text layer is drawn under the symbol layer when changing the style with the controls. Is there a way to avoid this? NOTE: The symbol layer uses an image created from a template: white triangle with red borders, one of the standard icons available to use

Comment: The `map.clear` function clears any things you added to the map, including layers. This function used to only remove user added layers, but it looks like this isn't the case currently. The Azure Maps team changed how map styles work this year, I suspect to enable custom styling of the basemap in the future.  So not sure if this is something they will revert. I'll let them know this behavior has changed.

Comment: Digging into the source code I can confirm they really messed up how the clear function works in the last 6 months or so. I reported this to their team. I've updated my response to include a function to remove all content added by users of the map.

Comment: For the layering order change, when you add your layer to the map, what are you putting as the 'before' value to get your layer under another. Is it the name of one of your layers or something else?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies, your updated code works! For the layering, I put the name of the layer that I want above the newly added layer, yes.

Comment: For extra context: The layering problems all seem to have to do something with custom patterns (created with 'map.imageSprite.createFromTemplate'). The layering works *until* a map style change occurs (e.g. road to grayscale). After this style change, the layers with the image sprites appear above the other layers (can be a coincidence).